# Cisco SD-WAN Cloud OnRamp Configuration

Tags: cisco, aws

I'm configuring a user per the instructions https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/sdwan/configuration/cloudonramp/ios-xe-17/cloud-onramp-book-xe/cloud-onramp-multi-cloud.html#concept_qqq_mly_hmb

In the section "Create AWS Cloud Account", step 7 it says choose Key or IAM Role.  I have an IAM User created in AWS and I have an API Key and Secret.

Cisco vManage is going to use this user to do whatever it needs in AWS.  What permissions does Cisco vManage need?  The documentation doesn't say.

Comment: You’ll need to reach out to AWS support for that answer. User permissions have nothing to do with networking, which means it’s off limits here.  You can try asking on [su] or [sf] but you may be told the same thing since it’s a permissions thing that may or may not be situational and be out of anyone’s control but yours and AWS support.

Comment: How is AWS support supposed to know what permissions the Cisco vManage software requires to do whatever it needs to do?

Comment: You asked what “AWS permissions” you needed to give the user. If you wanted to ask something else you should ask it instead of what you actually asked.  As it is, the permissions you’re requesting are on the AWS side, so AWS support should know the answer.

Comment: I've updated the question, is that more clear?

Comment: Inside of the document you linked, there’s a link to a document on the AWS side that says what permissions to assign the user. Have you read it?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html. It’s in step 7, section “a”, sub-section “1.”.

Comment: Yes, your edit makes it clearer what you’re looking for, however it’s still really off limits here since it’s got nothing to do with Layers 1-4, so I can’t really post anything as an answer.  However, see my comment above.

Comment: The document you linked doesn't say "what" permissions to assign, it describes "how" to assign permissions.  I am asking what permissions Cisco vManage requires.

Comment: Also, questions don't have to be specifically about "Layers 1 - 4" per "What topics can I ask here", this is question is about a tool used by networking professionals, Cisco vManage, to operate and maintain an enterprise network.

Comment: Sort of. If it were about using a tool to actually manage the network (such as configure a device or make a firewall rule), that would be on topic, however your question is about getting the tool to work in the first place, which is a host issue as well as a permissions issue.  Both of which are NOT networking questions.  I’ll leave it up to the moderators to determine, though.

Comment: I’m not familiar with Cisco vManage personally, so I can’t answer your question without researching it myself.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps outlined in the documentation, "Create AWS Cloud Account", https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/sdwan/configuration/cloudonramp/ios-xe-17/cloud-onramp-book-xe/cloud-onramp-multi-cloud.html#concept_qqq_mly_hmb.  At Step 7, there are two options: **Key** or **IAM Role**.

For the **Key** option create an IAM User and attach policies to the user account.

For the **IAM Role** option create an IAM Role to be assumed by Cisco vManage and attach policies to the role.

Attach the following AWS Managed Policies to the IAM User or Role:

- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- IAMReadOnlyAccess
- AWSNetworkManagerFullAccess
- AWSResourceAccessManagerFullAccess